# What did the [C]: Control production use for their cel-shading?

Tags: anime-production, c-control

I noticed at some parts of the CG seems to be different, the most obvious part is with Masakaki, who seems to look more doll-like then what he normally is. Another part I think may have been cel-shaded is when Msyu is exercising.

I am wondering if C for Control uses a mix of normal 2d animation that we normally see in anime and cel-shading for rendered scenes.

[image: Masakakis]

Comment: This one looks like CG 3D with cel-shading and a 2D drawn overlay on top. And before cel-shading became viable people used to outline and draw over the usual 3D models, so this doesn't seem very unusual, at least to me.

Comment: For this particular title, [WELZ Animation Studio](http://www.welzanimation.com/) was responsible for the OP and they are primarily a 3DS Max Shop (but they do do some woth with Maya). [Atelier Bitol](http://bitol.co.jp/) and [MADBOX](http://www.madbox.jp/) handled much of the CG for the actual episodes. Looking through the various Linkedin profiles of past employees and current employees seem to indicate that both companies worked with both 3DS Max and Maya. The details on the exact techniques or render have not been publicly disclosed, so we may never know~